# Spring Url request parameters not found

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

Hello im writing a REST controller and coming to an interesting issue

if have a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getAfterSalesFiles(@PathParam("store") final String store,
                                         @PathParam("filter") final String filter,
                                         @PathParam("sort") final Pageable pageable) {

    System.out.println("filter " + filter);
    System.out.println("page " + pageable.getPageNumber());
    System.out.println("size " + pageable.getPageSize());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and when i execute following curl command

```
curl localhost:8109/product/test?page=3&size=25&filter=cookies
```

i get the following in my console

```
filter null
page 3
size 20
```

so the page is correct, size and filter are wrong
if i swap the variables around in the url, the first parameter is correct the others are wrong

edit:
ive also tried

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getAfterSalesFiles(@RequestParam(value = "store") final String store,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "filter") final String filter,
                                         @RequestParam(value ="sort") final Pageable pageable) {

    System.out.println("filter " + filter);
    System.out.println("page " + pageable.getPageNumber());
    System.out.println("size " + pageable.getPageSize());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and with the curl

```
curl localhost:8109/product/test?filter=cookies&store=bavo&size=25&page=3
```

and then i get following output

```
{"timestamp":1438087790411,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required String parameter 'store' is not present","path":"/product/test"}
```

Any ideas for me where to look / how to debug this?

Regards,
Bakil

Comment: you mean `@PathVariable`, right?

Comment: no as i dont have it encoded in the URL like localhost/{size} but as localhost?size

Comment: then it's a `@RequestParam`? `@PathParam` is not a Spring annotation...

Comment: please read the original question it has been updated 0:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand character `&` tells the shell to run the curl command in the background and ends the command; that's why you're also getting the "command not found" errors you neglected to mention.

Put the entire URI inside quotes.